# Read value from AWS Secrets Manager and replace a placeholder in the Springboot property values

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

Our application needs to connect to confluent kafka and thus we have the following setups inside application.yaml file

```
kafka:
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username={userName}   password={passWord};
```

The {userName} and {passWord} need to be replaced by value fetching from AWS secret manager. These are what I have done so far.

Step 1: Use the following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Step 2: Create a configuration class and create a method annotated with @Bean to init a AWSSecretsManager client object.And we can get some key value pairs by using AWSSecretsManager object.

```
// Create a Secrets Manager client
AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
        .build();
```

I have the following questions to ask:

1. How can we inject the value we get from secret manager and replace the placeholder in the application.yml file?
2. To access AWSSecretsManager we need to pass AWS accessKey and seretKey. What is a good practice to provide those two values?

Some more info:

our application will be running on AWS ECS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this via Java code at all. I would totally remove the `aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager` dependency, and use the [ECS support for injecting SecretsManager values as environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html).

Comment: appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**My answer here will focus on the Secrets Manager API part of your question**

I recommend that you move from **AWS SDK for Java V1** to **AWS SDK for Java V2**. You can find V2 Java Secret Manager examples here.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager

Here is the Service Client for V2.

```
 SecretsManagerClient secretsClient = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();
```

In this example, I am using a ProfileCredentialsProvider that reads creds from .aws/Credentials. You can learn more about how V2 handles creds in the *AWS Java V2 DEV Guide*.

[Using credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html)

You cannot use **ProfileCredentialsProvider** in an app deployed to a container as this file structure not part of the container. So you can use Amazon ECS container credentials:

**The SDK uses the ContainerCredentialsProvider class to load credentials from the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI system environment variable.**

See point 5 in the above Doc.

Answer (score 0):

**Read value from AWS secrets manager using java - spring boot**

using below code you can fetch the values from AWS secrets manager for Kafka credentials.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueResponse;

@Configuration
public class SecretManagerSdk {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecretManagerSdk.class); 
    
    @Value("${mskRegion}")
    private String mskRegion;

    @Value("${secretName}")
    private String amazonSecretName;

    public String getSecretKey() {

        try {
         log.info("SDK - start");
           String mysecrets = this.getSecret();
            log.info("SDK - end");
            return mysecrets;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;

        }       
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        log.info("getting secret values");
        String secretName = amazonSecretName;
        Region region = Region.of(mskRegion);

        // Creating a Secrets Manager client
        SecretsManagerClient client = SecretsManagerClient.builder().region(region).build();
        GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder().secretId(secretName).build();
        GetSecretValueResponse getSecretValueResponse;
        try {
            getSecretValueResponse = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
       
           throw e;
        }
        String secret = getSecretValueResponse.secretString();
        log.info("Secret fetched");
        return secret;
    }
}
```

configuration changes in application.properties

```
mskRegion = ap-south-1
secretName = *************
```

add maven dependency on pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.14</version>
</dependency>
```